# Use xib file from a static library(sub project) bundle in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have a Static Library as a sub-project in Xcode 5. The library has a ViewController.h and .m file and ViewController in a bundle in the same library.

I am able to load the xib file from the library in code:

```
[NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyBundleNAme" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
```

But how would you make Storyboard load this xib file?

I have tried to delete the view in Storyboard ViewController. Also named the xib file with the same name as the ViewController set in the Interface builder Inspector Custom Class.

Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: I wouldn't.  I would give it a class convenience method that creates the view controller and loads it from the nib file and then allow the caller to present the view controller as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I was considering this as well.